# how to starting blocking in an android service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-service

I have a service which I call from my mainActivity.

here is the onStart method

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand service");
    stopPolling = false;
    startPolling();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

now when I start this service from the main activity it runs this method. Now obviously if i am going to block in my `startPolling()` method it will not return and my main activity will not respond.

How am I meant to start polling ? I am sure that i am missing some simple aspect of an android service which will allow for me to block.

EDIT:
I was just reading on the android site and it appears that I have missed a vital sentence:
"if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work".

I guess I am going to have to rethink my plan....

Answer (score 1):

> How am I meant to start polling ?

Well, polling is generally considered to be a programming technique of last resort. Ideally, find some event-driven way to find out whatever it you are trying to find out.

Beyond that, fork a thread.